# Java static class import in the declaring class

Tags: java, import

I have a class like:

```
 package com.example;

 public abstract class AbstractClass<S> {
       //stuffs
 }
```

Then a class that extends it, and define the generic type as its own inner class:

```
package com.example2;

import com.example.AbstractClass;
import com.example2.MyObject.MyObjectInnerClass;

public class MyObject extends AbstractClass<MyObjectInnerClass> {

     //other stuffs

     public static class MyObjectInnerClass {

     }
}
```

Why is needed the import of `com.example2.MyObject.MyObjectInnerClass` if it stays in the same file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import com.example.AbstractClass;
import com.example2.MyObject.MyObjectInnerClass;

public class MyObject extends AbstractClass<MyObjectInnerClass> {
```

It is needed because the *nested* (not inner) class `MyObjectInnerClass` only exists with an unqualifed name inside the `{`, which comes after the use of it in the `extends`clause.

A more conventional way of writing it would be:

```
import com.example.AbstractClass;

public class MyObject extends AbstractClass<MyObject .MyObjectInnerClass> {
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it actually gives the reason why.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by saying - it's not an inner class, it's a nested class (inner class is a non-static nested class).

That import is needed for two important reasons:

1. It needs to know which class do you mean - You could also have MyObjectInnerClass as a class in the same package as MyObject. Importless reference to such class would point to exactly that one.
2. That's what nested classes are for - to group classes in a logical hierarchical structure.

Note that it is customary to, instead of import, write `MyObject.MyObjectInnerClass` to put emphasis on the relationship between the two.

Comment: (1) isn't correct at all: either the import or the qualification is required regardless of whether there is any ambiguity. (2) isn't a reason why the import is required.

Comment: @EJP (1) is correct - since we're talking about language specification the possibility of ambiguity is enough to make import neccessery, and that's what I wrote. As for (2)... True

Comment: It is *not* necessary. You can write the FQN. No ambiguity there.